# Understanding JS try and catch statements (for adding a custom Modernizr test)

Tags: javascript, try-catch, modernizr

I'm currently using two Modernizr tests combined to provide a convenience feature fork. The two Modernizr tests I'm employing are 'blob' and 'SMIL'.

However, as I'm only using these two tests in my Modernizr build for this convenience I want to combine the tests into a single custom test that has a more meaningful name. For example:

```
;(function enhancedTest() {
    Modernizr.addTest('enhanced', function () {
         try {
            return !!new Blob();
            return !!document.createElementNS &&
                  /SVGAnimate/.test(toStringFn.call(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate')));
         } catch (e) {
            return false;
         }
    }, {
         aliases: ['enhanced']
    });
})();
```

I basically want the test to fail if the device does not support **either** of the return parts inside the `try` . If the device supports both, it should pass.

I've never written anything with try and catch before and I wondered whether this will work as I expect?

My concern is that currently, if it succeeds on the first `return !!new Blob()` it will pass the test (even though it may fail on the second part).

Is this the case? Or how should I refactor the code to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is that currently, if it succeeds on the first return `!!new Blob()` it will pass the test (even though it may fail on the second part).

You are right.

Try:

```
Modernizr.addTest(
  'enhanced',
  function() {
    try {
      new Blob(); // this line can throw an exception.
      return !!document.createElementNS && /SVGAnimate/.test( toStringFn.call( document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate') ) );
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. Could you explain why this works (I see that the `!!new` has been changed to `new` but I am unsure why that makes it work)?

Comment: If `Blob` object is not recognized, an exception will be thrown. The `catch` block handles this exception and `return false`. Double exclamation `!!` converts the result of `new Blob()` to boolean. If `Blob` is recognized, then `return !!new Blob()` is the same as `return true`. So the second test will never be executed.